# Java. setIconImage();

Tags: java

Хочется узнать как установить иконку.
Создаю Swing dialog, ему пытаюсь назначить иконку.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("static/icon.png");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что вы делаете с полученным изображением?

По идее вам надо это изображение присвоить значку окна. Делается это так:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("static/icon.png");
JDialog dialog = new Jdialog();
dialog.setIconImage(image);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

**UPDATED:** через JFrame делаете вероятно как-то так:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("static/icon.png");
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple frame");
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame);
((java.awt.Frame)dialog .getOwner()).setIconImage(image);
dialog .setModal(true);
dialog .setVisible(true);
```

Стряхнул пыль с Eclipse, чтобы найти где же ошибка закралась...

Вероятно вы запускаете программу из самой среды разработки. У вас директория **static** (как я понимаю с ресурсами) лежит в директории **src**. Но при запуске из среды программа стартует не из директории **src**, а на уровень выше. Естественно, когда он пытается найти путь **static/icon.png** у программы ничего не выходит и она не устанавливает иконку.

Просто вынесите директорию **static** на уровень выше.

Comment: Да, именно так и делаю, только в JDialog передаю new JFrame()

Comment: @dimka3210, обновил ответ.

Comment: Проблемв была в том, что я запускал из IntelliJ. А в ней какие то свои относительные пути. Если запускать из терминала, то всё ок.